# Trapped in log in loop after enabling auto-login

Tags: login, autologin

I am running Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa with kernel `5.4.0-72-generic x86_64`.

I enabled automatic logins in the settings menu. Since then, I cannot log in at all. The log-in screen resets every 5 seconds. I tried to bypass this with `ctl-alt-f1` and log in through the terminal, but the log-in screen keeps resetting faster than I can finish typing in my username and password.

I am able to boot into recovery mode and open a root shell, but I don't know how to go about disabling auto-logins from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to open `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and delete or comment out the lines

```
autologin-user=username
autologin-user-timeout=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to a non-GUI (command line) login screen. You may have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the `login:`  prompt.

Login, using your userid and password.

Since I don't know which window manager you're using, this is the hard way:

Type the command:

```
sudo find /etc -type f -print | xargs sudo grep $USER
```

to find all the files in `/etc` that mention your userid.

After setting user `walt4` to automatic login on my Ubuntu 18.04.05, I found:

```
sudo find /etc -type f -print | xargs sudo grep walt4
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf:AutomaticLogin=walt4
```

On further investigation I found that, on my system (YMMV) `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` contained the lines:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=walt4
```

Simply changing "`True`" to "`False`" disabled Automatic Login.

To disable Automatic Login on MY system (again YMMV), do:

```
sudo perl -pi~ -e "s/AutomaticLoginEnable=True/AutomaticLoginEnable=False/" /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```